# Notifications not pushing when app is closed/in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, notifications, alarm

I have a problem with notification not pushing when the app is not on. It fires when the app is started, but not in background. I've tried to play with the premissions, but It still doesn't help. Anybody knows whats wrong?

This is the code I have right now:

NotiUtils class:

```
class NotiUtils(base: Context) : ContextWrapper(base) {
    val MYCHANNEL_ID = "101"
    val MYCHANNEL_NAME = "App Alert Notification"
    val motivation: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("S chutí do toho a půl je hotovo!", "Tajemstvím úspěchu je začít.", "Štěstí tvého života záleží na druhu tvých myšlenek.", "Pokud napravíte svou mysl, zbytek vašeho života se zařadí na správné místo.", "Věř, běž a dokážeš.")

    private var manager: NotificationManager? = null

    init {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createChannels()
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createChannels() {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(MYCHANNEL_ID, MYCHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        channel.enableVibration(true)

        getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    fun getManager() : NotificationManager {
        if (manager == null) manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        return manager as NotificationManager
    }

    fun getNotificationBuilder(): NotificationCompat.Builder {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        return NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, MYCHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Nové úkoly")
            .setContentText(motivation.random())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mindhelper_noti)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver class:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val notificationUtils = NotiUtils(context)
        val notification = notificationUtils.getNotificationBuilder().build()
        notificationUtils.getManager().notify(150, notification)

        val sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        sharedPrefs.edit {
            putBoolean("checkbox1", false).apply()
            putBoolean("checkbox2", false).apply()
            putBoolean("checkbox3", false).apply()
        }

        val updateCheckboxesIntent = Intent("com.example.mindhelper.UPDATE_CHECKBOXES")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
            .sendBroadcast(updateCheckboxesIntent)
    }
}
```

Main Activity class, here i set the alarm, i've tried to play with the premission, but it always says that it was not granted:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var alarmMgr: AlarmManager? = null
    private lateinit var alarmIntent: PendingIntent

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    private val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 123

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mainContainer) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNav)
        setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController)

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.SET_ALARM
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SET_ALARM),
                REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }else{
            alarmSet()

            val alarmServiceIntent = Intent(this, AlarmService::class.java)
            startService(alarmServiceIntent)
        }

    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                alarmSet()

                val alarmServiceIntent = Intent(this, AlarmService::class.java)
                startService(alarmServiceIntent)
            } else {
                val message = "Permissions not granted."
                val duration = android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                val toast = android.widget.Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, duration)
                toast.show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun alarmSet(){
        alarmMgr = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmIntent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        }

        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
        }

        alarmMgr?.cancel(alarmIntent)

        alarmMgr?.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC,
            calendar.timeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            alarmIntent
        )
    }
}
```

Note, that it worked fine within emulator or testing on real device through the device manager, but when i installed it through the apk, it stopped working properly and won't fire the notification

Thanks in advance for helping.